# Steps to create javascript objects from text data out of a csv file using no libraries

Tags: javascript, csv, javascript-objects

I need to convert data from a csv file into a JavaScript object where key for each object is the id from the data. One JS object per each user.

**Question:** Is there a way to solve it using vanilla JS?

I need at the least a general walkthrough of what to do cause all I've been able to find is methods on how to solve this by using jQuery or JSON but for the research I am trying to understand, I can't use a specialized library, I'm only allowed to use plain VanillaJS.

**Sample text data:**

```
id  first_name    last_name    email                gender
--  ----------    ---------    -----                ------
1   Gloria        Mendez       gmendez@ipu.gov      Female
2   Lucy          Grey         lgrey@gmail.com      Female
3   Max           Mcolom       mmcolom@yahoo.com    Male
4   David         Cooke        dcooke@gmail.com     Male
5   Marwin        Darge        mdarge@gov.com       Male

hundreds of other rows
```

**Desired output:**

```
{
  1: { 
    id: 1, first_name: 'Gloria', last_name: 'Mendez', email: 'gmendez@ipu.gov', gender: 'female'
  },
  2: {
    id: 1, first_name: 'Lucy', last_name: 'Grey', email: 'lgrey@gmail.com', gender: 'female'
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: Is this on a webpage or in Node? How are you reading the file? At any rate, once you sort those out it should be fairly easy - read the first row, split on whitespace and you get the keys - keep those then use them when you read each following row as values.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response, it is on a webpage, and for the reading part, I was playing along with this [code](https://mounirmesselmeni.github.io/2012/11/20/reading-csv-file-with-javascript-and-html5-file-api/), but not quite sure if I'm doing it correctly, I am using their fileReader object (forgive my ignorance, I am a newby in jS)

Comment: This isn't a csv file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using vanilla JS below.

I've added comments to explain what the code is doing. It;s basically splitting the data into rows, and then cells, and doing array manipulation along the way:

```js
let table =
`id  first_name    last_name    email                gender
--  ----------    ---------    -----                ------
1   Gloria        Mendez       gmendez@ipu.gov      Female
2   Lucy          Grey         lgrey@gmail.com      Female
3   Max           Mcolom       mmcolom@yahoo.com    Male
4   David         Cooke        dcooke@gmail.com     Male
5   Marwin        Darge        mdarge@gov.com       Male`

// Split into rows, and then split each row into cells
let rows = table.split(/[\r\n]+/g).map(row => row.trim().split(/[\s\t]+/g));
// The first row will be the header
let header = rows[0];
// The rest is the data
let data = rows.slice(2);


// Create a function to return the desired object structure
function formatObject(headers, cells) {
  return headers.reduce((result, header, idx) => {
    result[header] = cells[idx];
    return result;
  }, {});
}

// Reduce each row into the desired format, and use the ID as a key
let result = data.reduce((res, row, idx) => {
  let value = formatObject(header, row);
  res[value.id] = value;
  return res;
}, {});

// Log the result
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Just one thing, the code you provided returns an array of objects correct? But what I need is one object, which whose keys are the id and the value is 1 user.  

The `desired output` in my original question, is how they want it to be.

Comment: Here you go, I've made the change. Try that

Comment: This seems to have done it. Now the only problem is understanding what your code is doing lol. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 3):

## Parse the file

- split on line break `\n`, to get rows

`const rows = csv.split('\n');`

- split each row on comma `,` to get cells (if it's CSV, otherwise, `\t` for TSV)

`const rawData = rows.map(d => d.split(',');`

## Extract the headers from the 1st row

The first row of data is you list of keys to build objects

`const headers = rawData[0]`

## Convert rows into objects

```
const data = rawData.slice(2); // get rid of first 2 rows
const output = data.map(row => {
   const obj = {};
   headers.forEach((h, i) => obj[h] = row[i] });   
   return obj;
});
```

Of course, you need to handle all sorts of edge cases, like commas in the CSV cell, missing data etc...

I hope this gets you started.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are loading the data already, you could loop through the data and use javascripts object bracket notation to define the new properties based on the id.

If you are looking for step by step,

1. first load the csv using something like node's fs module or the filereader in the browser.
2. for each line read parse the csv with javascript split.
3. if the assuming the id is always the first column you can now get
   the id of the data with the splitArray[0].
4. Create a new object, then use bracket notation to set the property
   of the object to the id.  ex.

   `var obj = {}; 
   obj[splitArray[0]] = data;`

This is really rough, untested, but should get you closer to where you need to go.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a double quoted comma separated file which is about the most common `csv` format:

```js
/* empty lines shown on purpose to approximate real file */
const csvString = 
`"id","first_name","last_name","email","gender"

"1","Gloria","Mendez","gmendez@ipu.gov","Female"
"2","Lucy","Grey","lgrey@gmail.com","Female"
"3","Max","Mcolom","mmcolom@yahoo.com","Male"

"4","David","Cooke","dcooke@gmail.com","Male"
"5","Marwin","Darge","mdarge@gov.com","Male"`;


//split string  on line breaks into array of line strings
const csvLines=csvString.split('\n');
// filter empty lines out and map each line to sub array
let arr = csvLines.filter(s=>s.trim()).map(arrFromLine)
// get headings from first line
let headings = arr.shift();
// map all the other lines into objects
let res = arr.map(lineArr =>{
   return lineArr.reduce((a,c, i)=>{
      a[headings[i]] = c;
      return a
   },{})
});

// map lines to array helper function
function arrFromLine(str){
   // remove quotes on each end, split at `","` to avoid any other commas in text
   return str.trim().slice(1, str.length-1).split('","');    
}

console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important;}
```